# Android NDK gives segmentation fault when throwing any exception

Tags: android, c++, exception, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I have a weird problem with Android NDK, it gives a segmentation fault as soon as I throw an exception, no matter how simple the exception is. I've simplified the code all the way down to this.

```
void android_main(struct android_app* state) {
    try {
        throw 0; // Whenever I hit a throw line like this I get segmentation fault
    }
    catch (...) {
       // This is never reached
    }
}
```

I have -fexception enabled, it happens in both debug and release builds and is using Android NDK version 13b.
Anyone have any idea of what is going on?

My only wild guess is that it has something to do with static variables initialized before android_main(), but they shouldn't be a part of the stack unwinding or whatever it is giving a segmentation fault.

Comment: Which compiler and runtime support?  Also have you enabled exceptions and possibly RTTI with compiler switches.  In the past (2 years ago) exceptions were off by default and only some of the supplied runtime support libraries supported exceptions.  You need to read the section on exceptions and RTTI in the current readme docs.

Comment: Clang 3.8 (the one that comes with visual studio), rtti and exceptions are enabled. I'll take a closer look at the readme docs.

Comment: @ViktorSehr could you provide detailed description for your build process?

Comment: @Sergio I'm basically using the default project which comes with Visual Studio. I build a .so library and then a package project which transforms to an .apk file. If pretty much flipped every compiler flag I can :(

Comment: @ViktorSehr okay, then please provide list of native libs within your APK, mention from which of them you're trying to throw an exception and crash trace from logcat.

Comment: @Sergio I appreciate taking your time, but I think I'll remake my project from scratch as there seems something really fishy is going on.